# Unable to connect testpmd to OVS+DPDK

Tags: networking, openvswitch, dpdk

## Summary

I'm trying to use testpmd as a sink of traffic from a physical NIC, through OVS with DPDK.

When I run testpmd, it fails. The error message is very brief, so I have no idea what's wrong.

How can I get testpmd to connect to a virtual port in OVS with DPDK ?

## Steps

I'm mostly following [these Mellanox instructions](https://community.mellanox.com/docs/DOC-3073#jive_content_id_OVS_Configuration).

```
# step 5 - "Specify initial Open vSwitch (OVS) database to use"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts
export DB_SOCK=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock
ovsdb-tool create /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db /usr/local/share/openvswitch/vswitch.ovsschema
ovsdb-server --remote=punix:$DB_SOCK --remote=db:Open_vSwitch,Open_vSwitch,manager_options --pidfile --detach

# step 6 - "Configure OVS to support DPDK ports"
ovs-vsctl --no-wait set Open_vSwitch . other_config:dpdk-init=true

# step 7 - "Start OVS-DPDK service"
ovs-ctl --no-ovsdb-server --db-sock="$DB_SOCK" start # what does this do? I forget

# step 8 - "Configure the source code analyzer (PMD) to work with 2G hugespages and NUMA node0"
ovs-vsctl --no-wait set Open_vSwitch . other_config:dpdk-socket-mem="2048,2048" # 2048 = 2GB


# step 9 - "Set core mask to enable several PMDs"
ovs-vsctl --no-wait set Open_vSwitch . other_config:pmd-cpu-mask=0xFF0 # cores 4-11, 4 per NUMA node

# core masks are one's hot. LSB is core 0
ovs-vsctl --no-wait set Open_vSwitch . other_config:dpdk-lcore-mask=0x8 # core 3

# step 10 - there is no step 10 in the doc linked above

# step 11 - Create an OVS bridge
BRIDGE="br0"
ovs-vsctl add-br $BRIDGE -- set bridge br0 datapath_type=netdev
```

Then for the OVS elements I'm trying to follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573450/problem-with-testpmd-on-dpdk-and-ovs-in-ubuntu-18-04)

```
# add physical NICs to bridge, must be named dpdk(\d+)
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port $BRIDGE dpdk0 \
   -- set Interface dpdk0 type=dpdk \
   options:dpdk-devargs=0000:5e:00.0 ofport_request=1
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port $BRIDGE dpdk1 \
   -- set Interface dpdk1 type=dpdk \
   options:dpdk-devargs=0000:5e:00.1 ofport_request=2

# add a virtual port to connect to testpmd/VM
# Not sure if I want dpdkvhostuser or dpdkvhostuserclient
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port $BRIDGE dpdkvhostuser0 \
   -- \
   set Interface dpdkvhostuser0 \
   type=dpdkvhostuser \
   options:n_rxq=2,pmd-rxq-affinity="0:4,1:6"  \
   ofport_request=3

sudo ovs-vsctl add-port $BRIDGE dpdkvhostuser1 \
   -- \
   set Interface dpdkvhostuser1 \
   type=dpdkvhostuser \
   options:n_rxq=2,pmd-rxq-affinity="0:8,1:10"  \
   ofport_request=4

# add flows to join interfaces (based on ofport_request numbers)
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow $BRIDGE in_port=1,action=output:3
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow $BRIDGE in_port=3,action=output:1
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow $BRIDGE in_port=2,action=output:4
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow $BRIDGE in_port=4,action=output:2
```

Then I run testpmd

```
sudo -E $DPDK_DIR/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd  \
   --vdev virtio_user0,path=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser0 \
   --vdev virtio_user1,path=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser1 \
   -c 0x00fff000  \
   -n 1 \
   --socket-mem=2048,2048  \
   --file-prefix=testpmd \
   --log-level=9 \
   --no-pci \
   -- \
   --port-numa-config=0,0,1,0 \
   --ring-numa-config=0,1,0,1,1,0 \
   --numa  \
   --socket-num=0 \
   --txd=512 \
   --rxd=512 \
   --mbcache=512 \
   --rxq=1 \
   --txq=1 \
   --nb-cores=4 \
   -i \
   --rss-udp \
   --auto-start
```

The output is:

```
...
EAL: lcore 18 is ready (tid=456c700;cpuset=[18])
EAL: lcore 21 is ready (tid=2d69700;cpuset=[21])
Interactive-mode selected
Auto-start selected
Warning: NUMA should be configured manually by using --port-numa-config and --ring-numa-config parameters along with --numa.
USER1: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_0>: n=327680, size=2176, socket=0
USER1: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_1>: n=327680, size=2176, socket=1
Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Fail to configure port 0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Start ports failed
```

The bottom of `/usr/local/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log` is

```
2018-11-30T02:45:49.115Z|00026|netdev_dpdk|INFO|vHost Device '/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser0' has been added on numa node 0
2018-11-30T02:45:49.115Z|00027|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENABLE
2018-11-30T02:45:49.115Z|00028|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: set queue enable: 1 to qp idx: 0
2018-11-30T02:45:49.115Z|00029|netdev_dpdk|INFO|State of queue 0 ( tx_qid 0 ) of vhost device '/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser0'changed to 'enabled'
2018-11-30T02:45:49.115Z|00030|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: read message VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENABLE
2018-11-30T02:45:49.115Z|00031|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: set queue enable: 1 to qp idx: 1
2018-11-30T02:45:49.278Z|00032|dpdk|ERR|VHOST_CONFIG: recvmsg failed
2018-11-30T02:45:49.279Z|00033|dpdk|INFO|VHOST_CONFIG: vhost peer closed
2018-11-30T02:45:49.280Z|00034|netdev_dpdk|INFO|vHost Device '/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser0' has been removed
```

What is the cause of the failure?

Should I use a dpdkvhostuserclient instead of dpdkvhostuser ?

## What else I've tried

- Looking in `/var/log/messages` for more info - but that's just a copy of stdout and stderr.
- Rebooting
- Looking up the OVS docs, but they [don't mention "logs"](https://ovs-reviews.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=logs&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

I've tried changing my `testpmd` command arguments. (Docs [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html))

- Getting rid of `--no-pci`. The result is

  `Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
  Port 0: 24:8A:07:9E:94:94
  Configuring Port 1 (socket 0)
  Port 1: 24:8A:07:9E:94:95
  Configuring Port 2 (socket 0)
  Fail to configure port 2
  EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
    Cause: Start ports failed`

  Those MAC addresses are for the physical NICs I've already connected to OVS.
- Removing `--auto-start`: same result
- `--nb-cores=1`: same result
- Removing the 2nd `--vdev`: `Warning! Cannot handle an odd number of ports with the current port topology. Configuration must be changed to have an even number of ports, or relaunch application with --port-topology=chained`. When I add `--port-topology=chained` I end up with the original error.

## Other Info

- DPDK 17.11.4
- OVS 2.10.1
- NIC: Mellanox Connect-X5
- OS: Centos 7.5
- My NIC is on NUMA node 0
- When I run `ip addr` I see that an interface called `br0` has the same MAC address as my physical NICs (`p3p1`, when it was bound to the kernel)

When I run `sudo ovs-vsctl show` I see

```
d3e721eb-6aeb-44c0-9fa8-5fcf023008c5
    Bridge "br0"
        Port "dpdkvhostuser1"
            Interface "dpdkvhostuser1"
                type: dpdkvhostuser
                options: {n_rxq="2,pmd-rxq-affinity=0:8,1:10"}
        Port "dpdk1"
            Interface "dpdk1"
                type: dpdk
                options: {dpdk-devargs="0000:5e:00.1"}
        Port "dpdk0"
            Interface "dpdk0"
                type: dpdk
                options: {dpdk-devargs="0000:5e:00.0"}
        Port "br0"
            Interface "br0"
                type: internal
        Port "dpdkvhostuser0"
            Interface "dpdkvhostuser0"
                type: dpdkvhostuser
                options: {n_rxq="2,pmd-rxq-affinity=0:4,1:6"}
```

Edit: Added contents of `/usr/local/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log`

Comment: The OVS logs are usually in `/usr/local/var/log/openvswitch/` or `/var/log/openvswitch/`.

Comment: Thanks. `/usr/local/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log` says `dpdk|ERR|VHOST_CONFIG: recvmsg failed`. So now I just have to figure out what that means.

Answer (score 3):

1. Indeed, we need `dpdkvhostuser`, not client.
2. The number of queues is mismatch in OVS `options:n_rxq=2` vs testpmd `--txq=1`.

Comment: 1. Thanks
2. Good point. I fixed that, but now the result is still the same.